# How to completey remove hyper-v?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, hyper-v

Because of hyper-v installed I have conflict problem with another software so I went to windows 10 features and I unchecked hyper-v to uninstall but it leaves devices in device manager and network adapters. No matter I delete the devices and the network adapters it return again on next boot !!

So any advise to completely remove hyper-v ?

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://petri.com/how-to-disable-hyper-v-completely-in-windows-10

Comment: You probably don't need to remove it completely.  Sure.. you can go that route but you don't need to.  Set it as disabled in the bootloader and you should be fine.  Here is a [bone](https://www.google.com/search?channel=cus2&q=bcdedit+disable+hyper-v) to help you with this.  I myself have used BCDEdit to add a boot menu option in case I want to turn it on for a single boot.. by default, I too have it disabled.

Comment: What software is conflicting with Hyper-V not running (unchecked).  I assume you restarted after unchecking Hyper-V in Program Features.

Comment: @John Embarcadero Delphi

Comment: Interesting - Google Search does not show any conflict with Hyper-V.  Make sure Hyper-V is unchecked in Windows Features, restart, uninstall Embarcadero Delphi, restart and install Embarcadero Delphi again.

Comment: @Moab your link solved my problem , posted as answer ?

Answer (score -3):

Try to disable secureboot and you'll discover that hyper-v is disabled.

Comment: secure boot has nothing to do with Hyper-V