# How to get rid of Hyper-V vEthernet adapters after uninstalling Hyper-V?

Tags: virtualization, network-adapter

After removing Hyper-V and starting to use VMware instead, I am left with several network adapters that keep recreating themselves after reboot. This is a little annoying and has caused some issues. How can I permanently remove them?

Comment: Windows 10? If so see my comment here>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1573031/how-to-completey-remove-hyper-v?noredirect=1#comment2396714_1573031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Host Networking Service (HNS) works to attach virtual endpoints to a network. These are created by virtualizatipon applications like Hyper-V and Docker on Windows. You can remove them all with the following command:

```
Get-HNSNetwork | Remove-HNSNetwork
```